# get values from the chart with a mouse click that works in real time

Tags: r

For example, I have a graph from which I want to extract values. I can do it pretty easily if its values are static

```
offline <- rnorm(100)
plot(offline,t="l", main = "offline")

#  click on chart
click <- locator(n = 1)
abline(h = click$y,v = click$x, col=4,lty=2,lwd=2)


> click
$x
[1] 78.17894
$y
[1] 0.2361954
```

But what if my data comes online and is read continuously (like `online function`), can I extract the values without stopping the process?

```
online <- function(){
x <- rnorm(100)
while(T){
  ping <- sample(seq(0.005,0.1,by = 0.005), 1)
  Sys.sleep(time = ping)
  
  new_val <- rnorm(1)
  x <- tail(append(x,new_val),100)
  plot(x,t="l")
  
}
}
```

run

```
online()
```

Comment: Maybe try a package like [eventloop](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/eventloop).

Comment: Cool package but I have Windows OS

Comment: is there any reason you can't save the data directly by returning it from `online()`?

Comment: The data is analyzed in real time,
it makes no sense to save them to a file and then read real time from the file again. Get the same "online function" only slower

Comment: What are you doing with the data is the question. You are continuously collecting the data from the graph. Why not just collect it from another source rather than the graph? The graph is plotted then you click to collect the data. that means there is a data source where the data is obtained to be plotted. Collect it from that source

Comment: Hi! You didn't understand the question. The data is analyzed by a person, because it cannot be algorithmized. If it were possible to write an algorithm, then of course there was no need for a graph, no mouse clicks, or the person himself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question specifically mentions interacting with the graphics device using `locator()`, here is one approach.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(data.table)
online <- function(retrieve_after = 50){
  x <- rnorm(100)
  iter = 1
  while(T){
    iter <- iter+1
    print(iter)
    ping <- sample(seq(0.005,0.1,by = 0.005), 1)
    Sys.sleep(time = ping)
    new_val <- rnorm(1)
    x <- tail(append(x,new_val),100)

    plot(x,t="l")

    if(iter %% retrieve_after ==0) {
      print("**Getting data**")
      click <- locator(n = 1)
      print(click)
    }
    
  }
}
online()
```

This will let you interact with the chart at predefined intervals. These pauses could be defined by anything from pre-defined conditions to keypresses.

*Interacting with a plot is in general not the right way to retrieve data in R. You might check if one of these following approaches might suit your needs.*

---

**Classical R code**

Each of these 2 options will allow you to save the data after a number of iterations, so that the function is not slowed down in any significant way.

```
# option 1 ----------------------------------------------------------------
library(openxlsx)
library(data.table)
online <- function(save_after=100){
  x <- rnorm(100)
  iter = 1
  while(T){
    iter <- iter+1
    print(iter)
    ping <- sample(seq(0.005,0.1,by = 0.005), 1)
    Sys.sleep(time = ping)
    new_val <- rnorm(1)
    x <- tail(append(x,new_val),100)
    plot(x,t="l")
    if(iter %% save_after ==0) {
      print("**SAVED**")
      write.xlsx(data.frame(x), paste0("iteration", iter/100,".xlsx"))
    }
  }
}

online()
# retrieve full data after the run
fulldata <- rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern="iteration"), read.xlsx))


# option 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------
# better, because the loop is outside the function. functions should be kept short where possible

ping_once <- function() {
    rnorm(1) # equivalent to return(rnorm(1))
}

x <- rnorm(100)
iter = 1
save_after=100
while(T){
  iter <- iter+1
  print(iter)
  ping <- sample(seq(0.005,0.1,by = 0.005), 1)
  Sys.sleep(time = ping)
  new_val <- ping_once()
  x <- tail(append(x,new_val),100)
  plot(x,t="l")
  if(iter %% save_after ==0) {
    write.xlsx(data.frame(x), paste0("iteration", iter/100,".xlsx"))
  }
}
# retrieve full data after the run
fulldata <- rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern="iteration"), read.xlsx))
```

Comment: HI gaut! Your code above partially answers the question. It retrieves the value by stopping the whole process (pauses it), and my question was just
"can I extract the values without stopping the process?"

Process: is the constant flow of new data

Comment: the flow of data can be extracted continuously using any of the last 2 options. The plotting can be triggered at any time, as I did in the first option.If you're looking for a full-fledged realtime chart analysis software such as Metatrader, the scope of the question might be larger than R.

Comment: Okay, I understand you.
Let's do it this way, I'll wait a few days, then I'll accept your answer as correct

Comment: Totally up to you. It would probably help if you described your requirements a bit more. You need to be able to click on a running chart at anytime? what do you want to achieve exactly

Comment: " You need to be able to click on a running chart at anytime?"  yes, that's exactly what i want and also get values from click.    "what do you want to achieve exactly"  -  I want to make a small platform for trading on tick data (data is updated very quickly) for my needs. And click on the chart, I need to set an order for opening and closing positions, it is also possible to train algorithms online